# Button print not working in webbrower IE build ASP.NET Core 7 MVC + FastReport

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, fastreport

I created an app in ASP.NET Core 7 MVC and using FastReport.

View:

```
@await ViewBag.WebReport.Render();
```

Controller :

```
WebReport webReport = new WebReport();
var path = $"{_webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath}\\Report\\RptLichTruc.frx";

webReport.Report.Load(path);
ViewBag.WebReport = webReport;
```

[image]

But the print button is not working.

I was setup drive print